# Question about Unity C# skill cast interface and class design

Tags: unity, c#

So I have skill class and it's children which have the Use() interface and functionality code of the skill, what want to do is have the item can also be used to cast skill, or have some wrapper to record use time or consume item of a individual character or something like that, So what I came up is use a wrapper class to wrap the the skill functionality, like below:

```cs
public interface ICastable
{
    ICastable skill {get;}
}

public interface ICastOnSelf: ICastable
{
    void Use(GameObject user);
}

public interface ICastOnTarget: ICastable
{
    void Use(GameObject user, GameObject target);
}

public abstract class Skill: ScriptableObject {}

public class SomeSkillCastOnSelf: Skill, ICastOnSelf
{
    public ICastable skill {get { return this; }}
    public void Use(GameObject user)
    {
        print(something);
    }
}

public class SomeSkillCastOnTarget: Skill, ICastOnTarget
{
    public ICastable skill {get { return this; }}
    public void Use(GameObject user, GameObject target)
    {
        print(something);
    }
}

public class SomeItemContainsASkill: Item, ICastOnSelf, ICastOnTarget 
// Have to implement all interfaces since it could contains different kind of skill
{
    public ICastable skill {get { return acctualSkill; }}

    public Skill acctualSkill;

    public int timeUsed;

    public void Use(GameObject user)
    {
        var skillCastOnself = skill as ICastOnSelf;
        if (skillCastOnself == null)
        {
            print("Can't cast this skill on self")
            return;
        }
        skillCastOnself.Use(user);
        timeUsed += 1;
    }

    public void Use(GameObject user, GameObject target)
    {
        //same idea...
    }
}

public class SkillWapper: ICastOnSelf, ICastOnTarget
{
    //same idea as SomeItemContainsASkill class
}

public class Caster: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ICastable> wrappers;

    public IEnumrator cast()
    {
        foreach (var item in wrappers)
        {
            if (item.skill is ICastOnSelf)
            {
                // ... ask and wait for player input here
                item.Use(this)
            }
            else
            {
                // ... ask and wait for player input here
                item.Use(this, target)
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Inventory
{
    List<ItemSlot> items;
}

public class ItemSlot
{
    Item item;
    int stack;
}
```

edit: Inventory class contains itemslot which is recording the current stack of the item, but if I want to consume item after using it, there must be a way to reference to which inventory and which slot is using. so the difficulty of reference this is the Itemslot is wrapper class but itself could be a non ICastable class depending on the item it is holding. Hope this makes it more clear.
But the whole thing is kinda messy, so any idea of a better design? Thanks.

Comment: What aspect of the design is “messy” or doesn’t work for _you_? Broader code review advice is potentially better suited for the Code Review StackExchange site. Is there a specific aspect of this design that troubles you we can focus on here?

Comment: @Josh Acctually it's really hard to wrap mind around this design. Feel it's hard and I didn't really make myself clear. I just want to know if there is other opinions.

Comment: @Josh through ICastable interface I want to be able to use the skill, whether it is in a wrapper calss or not. But if it's a wrapper class, I need to implement the interface to use what's inside the wrapper class and, the code needs to know what's acctually inside the wrapper class if it's ICastable, then it is getting complicated

Comment: @Josh I have added more info hope that will make it more clear.

Comment: It sounds like you have items that may have skills associated with them that are activated when the item is consumed, and you’re trying to find an API design for that. Is that correct?

Comment: @Josh Yes you are right and I also would like it's extensible so I could associated other stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design does seem massively overcomplicated.

I find it useful to think about the divisions of responsibilities. You say that

- You want items that may have skills associated with them that activate when the item is used.
- Items in your inventory can be stacked and some items may be consumed when used.

These are two different things, and I believe that the responsibility for dealing with removing items that get consumed on use lies with the inventory system, *not* the skill system (nor the items themselves). If you have questions about that, I'd encourage you to ask them separately.

As for the skills, it seems to me like you can simplify greatly. I don't see the need for the number of interfaces in your example, and I don't understand the rationale for why you need these "wrapper" types.

I would expect to see a system that looked more like:

```
interface ICastable {
  // Returns true if the skill did successfully activate.
  bool Activate(GameObject caster, GameObject target);
}
```

Whether or not an `ICastable` supports self-targeting can simply be handled in `Activate`: if `caster == target`, return false for abilities that cannot self-target.

At the other end of thing, your `Item` class should just contain an optional reference to an `ICastable` that is the associated skill:

```
class Item {
  public ICastable OnUseSkill = null;

  void Use() { /* ... */ }
}
```

In `Use`, if `OnUseSkill` is non-null, call the `Activate` method. You'll need targeting information, naturally, but how you pass that depends on how you determine it at the gameplay level.

Comment: The reason I use serveral interfaces like ICastOnSelf is different skill need different input, some skill may require a Vector3 or int, and skill cast on self doesn't need ask User for additional input, so I think it's best to implement different interface so that following code know how to handle the skill and ask for User what kind of input. And the idea using wrapper is I want the skill class reusable, it's just  functionality of the skill, there maybe other stuff like consume charge or item following that

Comment: That doesn't sound like a particularly good reason to me, and since it's a large part of why your design is so complex, I'd recommend rethinking it. At the very least it's exceedingly unclear how the interfaces solve that problem since they distill everything down to a single "Use" function. Skills prompting for additional input themselves (rather than a higher-level system reading the skill data and gathering that input) also sounds very fishy to me. Finally, nothing about the wrapper class you've presented seems to do anything for "reusability" in the example you provided.

Comment: It sounds like you have quite a knot of interconnected problems that's probably outside the scope of a single question to drill down into. You may want to consider discussing your design and your goals in the [chat].

Comment: Is there any other place I could discuss with people? I don't have enough reputation to talk there.

Comment: There are various Discord servers for gamedev communities as well, such as the one linked at [GDNet](https://www.gamedev.net/community/chat/)